# Delete key and Backspace key not activating keyPressEvent in PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6

So in my program, the function keyPressEvent is not activating (its not entering the function block) for delete and backspace keys until I actually tap any button from the GUI. Suppose the function contains this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
         key = event.key()
         if key==Qt.Key.Key_0:
                  print('Its zero')
         elif key==Qt.Key.Key_Backspace:
                  print('Its backspace')
         elif key==Qt.Key.Key_Delete:
                  print('Its delete')
```

Here, Backspace or delete button in the keyboard does not work whatsoever (it does not activate keyPressEvent function).

I noticed that the two keys only work after I tap any button in the GUI, but not before that. Please help!

In case anyone wants to see the code, [here (Github link)](https://github.com/AnkurMal/Calculator/blob/main/Calculator_in_PyQt6.py) it is:

Comment: Please provide a [mre]